# How to make sure that a TCP transmission over java.net.Socket is successful?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, network-programming

To support label printing from my Android app, I'm using raw TCP connections to port 9100 of industrial label printers that support the ZPL command language.

It seems that the TCP/IP implementation of Android and/or certain label printers have a quirk that makes the data transmission error-prone...

I first encountered issues with the Godex ZX420i printer, where the printer's display would indicate that it's receiving data, but then it would do nothing and hang indefinitely until I rebooted it. The solution was to set `SO_SNDBUF` to 1024 via `Socket.setSendBufferSize()`. This was not documented anywhere, but I found it in Godex's Android SDK. (I wrote about the whole experience in detail in [this blog post](https://taylan-kammer.blogspot.com/2020/12/print-html-android-zpl.html), where I mention the TCP issue at the end.)

What's interesting is that if I connected to the ZX420i via `ncat` from my PC, I didn't have to do anything special. Making my app send the ZPL commands to my PC (using `ncat -l 9100 > test.zpl` to save them in a file) and then sending the ZPL commands to the printer from my PC (using `ncat printer_ip 9100 < test.zpl`) worked perfectly fine. Only Android, and also not all Android devices, had the issue.

(In my frustration I had even written equivalent Java code using OpenJDK on my PC and that also worked fine.)

Now I'm having a very similar issue with the TSC ME240 printer. Sending the ZPL commands from my Android app to a PC to save them in a file, then sending them to the printer, works fine. But when the Android app connects directly to the printer and sends the exact same commands, the printer simply does nothing.

Here's the Java code that I use in my app:

```java
// 'address' was set to 'new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, 9100)'
// 'output' refers to a ByteArrayOutputStream

try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
    socket.setSendBufferSize(1024);
    socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
    socket.connect(address);
    output.writeTo(socket.getOutputStream());
}
```

Any help on what might be causing the broken behavior on behalf of the printer would be greatly appreciated. The Godex ZX420i works perfectly fine since I added the `socket.setSendBufferSize(1024)` line (though it's a mystery why it's needed), but the TSC ME240 does nothing.

There ought to be a way to ensure that the TCP transmission works with any printer model, given that the TCP/IP implementation of MS Windows, or something that `ncat` does or whatever, seems to work reliably with any printer model.

*** **UPDATE** ***

I feel very stupid now, because in this case the issue was, after all, in the ZPL commands that I sent. I surpassed the maximum allowed size of the "print bitmap" command (^GF). The test I made where I sent the commands to my PC and then to the printer were with a smaller label.

**However,** I'm leaving the question open and considering it unsolved, because I still don't see why it should be necessary to set `SO_SNDBUF` to 1024 for some printers to work correctly, and would love to understand that. (In that case, it was definitely that, and not the bitmap size or anything else; I had sent the exact same bytes from Android and from my PC. This time I just jumped to conclusions because of that previous experience.)

Comment: `// 'output' refers to a ByteArrayOutputStream` Can be. But better post the code where you declare and initialise it and put the data in it as there is nothing to check for us now. Or what is it that you want us to do?

Comment: @blackapps the rest of the code contains nothing network-related. It's just populating `output` with the ZPL commands. And as I explained, the issue isn't there, as I can "fake" the printer on my PC via `ncat -l 9100` and successfully receive the ZPL commands from the app, then send them to the printer (again via ncat) and have them successfully executed by the printer. The problem is purely the TCP connection between Android and the printer.

Comment: Did you try to simply close the connection after sending?

Comment: @RonMaupin Java's try-with-resources syntax closes the socket automatically.

Comment: Try closing the connection after you have written everything in the stream.